# Remove file in C++ under UNIX

Tags: c++, unix, file-io, posix

How do you guys typically delete files on Linux OS? I am thinking of using the `unlink` function call, but I wonder if you have a better idea, as the C++ standard has no mention of file deletion operation and it is system dependent.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yep -- the C++ standard leaves this stuff up to the OS, so if you're on Linux (or any POSIX system), [`unlink()`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/unlink.html) is what you've got.

The C standard provides [`remove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove), which you could try, but keep in mind that its [behavior is unspecified](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG15/docs/rr/9945-1/9945-1-59.html) for anything other than a 'regular file', so it doesn't really shield you from getting into platform-specific filesystem details (links, etc).

If you want something higher-level, more robust, and more portable, check out [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

Comment: I use remove() in all my code - portability matters to some of us.

Comment: remove is in fact specified in POSIX to be equivalent to unlink for non-directories.

Answer (score 20):

The Standard includes a function called [remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/remove.html) which does that. Though i would prefer `boost.filesystem` for that (if i already use boost anyway).

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    std::remove("/home/js/file.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`unlink()` is defined by the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standards, and hence will exist on any POSIX compatible system, and on quite a few that aren't POSIX compatible too.

Answer (score 1):

unlink is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that recent kernels also offer `unlinkat`. This function is faster than `unlink` if you have a file descriptor on the directory itself.