# Program deleting file of other user

Tags: c++, linux, file, file-permissions

I have two Users. User1 is running a program which tries to delete a file from user2. But my program always return me "permission denied".

When I try to delete the file myself as user1 with the rm command there is no problem. The permission of the files are 775 and my user1 is in the group of user2. This group is also the owner of the files. The permission of the directory in which the files are is 775 too.

For removing the file the program I have written uses the "remove" function from c/c++.
Does anyone have a solution or idea ?

I have asked this question on unix.stackexchange.com before. They have sent me here.

Here is my code:

void deleteFile()
    {

```
    if(0 != remove("File1.txt"))
        cout<<"Error deleting File: "<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
    if(0 != remove("File2.txt"))
        cout<<"Error deleting File: "<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
}
```

i have renamed the files but i know the original paths are correct. i have already tested this

more information:
ok i have runnned the program as user2 and the files have been deleted without any problems.

`groups user1
users user2`

`groups user2
user2 adm www-data plugdev users ftp vsftpd`

`ls -lah
drwxrwxr-x 7 user2 user2 4.0K Nov 27 14:13 .
drwxrw-r-x 4 user2 user2 4.0K Nov 11 12:34 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user2 user2 50  Nov 12 15:12 File1.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user2 user2 826 Nov 27 14:13 File2.txt`

Comment: what's the ownership of the containing dir? mode 775 doesn't help much if it's in some OTHER group than what the files/users are.

Comment: What is the permissions of the executing program?

Comment: I thought the function for deleting a file was [`unlink`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678325/remove-file-in-c-under-unix

Comment: sorry but i can't understand what exactly you are meaning. the directory in wich the files are located is owned by user2 and the group "user2". You can see this in the output of ls -lah wich i have already posted in the question. 
Or do i misunderstand you ?

Comment: @BenVoigt the "remove" function is automatically calling unlink if the path point to a file. see man remove

Comment: @Camron_Godbout the permission of the executing program is also 775  
and is owned by user1 and the group user2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `rm` and Your command with `strace` as `user1`:

```
strace your_program
strace rm File1.txt File2.txt
```

You should see, what Your program and `rm` are doing differently.